Print View: Why Print view in chrome have half empty and content goes in next page?

I am try to print CR-80 card that is already printed but I only print values.
for setting Alignment when I increse margin/padding - [top] but last values goes to next page.
NOTE: I have removed and header footer but it did not do anything
Name:

ID NO:

Card No:

I am try to print CR-80 card with already printed value.


<div id="printablediv" class="hidden" style="font-family: Poppins; z-index: -1; overflow: hidden; font-size: 34px;">
   <div style="color: rgb(24, 52, 155); padding-top: 24px; font-weight: bolder; margin-left: 24px;">RASHIDI ALLY SIMBA</div>
   <div style="color: rgb(24, 52, 155); padding-top: 24px; font-weight: bolder; margin-left: 24px;">RASHIDI ALLY SIMBA</div>
   <div style="color: rgb(24, 52, 155); padding-top: 24px; font-weight: bolder; margin-left: 24px;">RASHIDI ALLY SIMBA</div>
   <div style="color: rgb(24, 52, 155); padding-top: 24px; font-weight: bolder; margin-left: 24px;">RASHIDI ALLY SIMBA</div>
   <div style="color: rgb(24, 52, 155); padding-top: 24px; font-weight: bolder; margin-left: 24px;">RASHIDI ALLY SIMBA</div>
   <style type="text/css" media="print">
      @page {
      size: 86mm 54mm;
      margin: 21.12px 37.44px 0px 0.96px;
      }
      // body {
      //     zoom: 200%;
      // }
      <div style="color: rgb(24, 52, 155); padding-top: 40px; font-weight: bolder; margin-left: 24px;">0  1203  2940  5008  4992</div>
   </style>
</div>




why is javascript at all relevant to this question? this is likely a CSS issue

I have tagged it because there could be a solution of javascript. @JaromandaX

front end javascript can't fix backend java problem

@Ivar I have shared my code can you please check it

So you are saying that this is the default behaviour of the browser we can't fix is? @JaromandaX

I am saying that CORS is controlled by the server. The browser deals with the hand it is dealt.
